# Facebook Conversion Pixel Value Sum

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I would like to know how to get sum of total value received from a conversion pixel during a campaign.

If I request ad stats for an ad group or ad campaign I can get how many times the conversion pixel is executed but not the sum of values sent during execution. Example response:

```
"actions" : {
"offsite_conversion.checkout" : NumberLong(17)
}
```

If I request conversion stats, I get the following response:

```
{
"action_type" : "offsite_conversion.checkout",
"object_id" : NumberLong("XXX"),
"post_click_1d" : NumberLong(7),
"post_click_7d" : NumberLong(7),
"post_click_28d" : NumberLong(7),
"post_imp_1d" : NumberLong(10),
"post_imp_7d" : NumberLong(12),
"post_imp_28d" : NumberLong(12),
"post_click_value_1d" : 314.78,
"post_click_value_7d" : 314.78,
"post_click_value_28d" : 314.78,
"post_imp_value_1d" : 232.06,
"post_imp_value_7d" : 261.07,
"post_imp_value_28d" : 261.07
}
```

So none of these responses are helpful if -let's say- I would like to know how much total revenue we get using a conversion pixel used in checkout with value, for each campaign or ad group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The total revenue can be calculated by adding:
revenue = post_click_value_28d + post_imp_value_1d

This is similar to how you calculate the total number of times the pixel has fired:
action_total = post_click_28d + post_imp_1d

I can't recall where I learned this, but it was not well documented within the Facebook API.

Comment: yeah, that is not documented and a couple of demonstrations show that you are right, thanks! is there any formula to calculate total conversion counts (not value)?